# Custom Action for BDC Entity adds Plus Symbols in Query String Parameters

Tags: custom-actions, custom-bdc, query-string

Using the web interface in SharePoint 2010, I add a custom action to one of my Business Data entities (External Content Type) to navigate to a URL with some parameters in the query string.  The link works fine but each parameter has a slew of plus symbols after it like this . . .

```
http://intranet/mysite/SitePages/CUSTRelated.aspx?DATAA=59147++++++++++++++++&DATAB=05110++++++++++
```

How do I get rid of this behavior?  I can post-process in this case but that will not always be an optimal solution especially when the query string is large.

Comment: It looks like the plus symbols are garbage from SQL--not from ECT Actions.  Character encoding maybe?

Comment: Okay.  The plus symbols are spaces that come from the SQL data.  They become plus symbols because they are not escaped by the BDC Action when it builds the query string.  Sounds like an oversight on MS's part to me.  I had to write my own jQuery/XSL in the Biz List web part page to make this work and escaped the data in the process.